# SQL: Two count functions in a single query?

Tags: sql

How do I get these two count functions into one query?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(MaritalStatus) as 'Married'
FROM 
    Person.Person PP 
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee HRE ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
WHERE 
    MaritalStatus = 'M';

SELECT 
    COUNT(MaritalStatus) as 'Single'
FROM 
    Person.Person PP 
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee HRE ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
WHERE 
    MaritalStatus = 'S';
```

Comment: The tricks is here to use conditional aggregation by implementing `COUNT` through `SUM`.  `SUM(CASE WHEN a=b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Your column aliases are non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using? In standard SQL you can use `count(*) filter (where MaritalStatus = 'S'`)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using sum case when:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MaritalStatus = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
SUM(CASE WHEN MaritalStatus = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM Person.Person PP INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee HRE
ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of request, you need to use aggregation functions.

```
SELECT MaritalStatus, COUNT(MaritalStatus)
FROM Person.Person PP
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee HRE
        ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY MaritalStatus;
```

This will output something like this:

```
MaritalStatus  | COUNT(MaritalStatus)
               |
M              | 50
S              | 20
```

As two rows. You can add 
`ORDER BY MaritalStatus` to ensure that you receive the data in the good order, because the order by which you receive the data is not deterministic.

The advantage of using this over SUM() is that if you ever add another marital status, your request would not change.

Comment: one point from me for mentioning the advantage over the SUM() technique.

Answer (score 1):

This also works and is easy enough to extend to other MaritalStatuses.

```
SELECT married.*, single.* from
(   SELECT COUNT(MaritalStatus) as 'Married'
    FROM Person.Person PP INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee HRE
    ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE MaritalStatus = 'M'
    ) married
, (
    SELECT COUNT(MaritalStatus) as 'Single'
    FROM Person.Person PP INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee HRE
    ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE MaritalStatus = 'S'
    ) single
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your from and join clauses are identical, simply move the where conditions into a case statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(case when MaritalStatus = 'M' then 1 end) as 'Married',
       COUNT(case when MaritalStatus = 'S' then 1 end) as 'Single'
FROM Person.Person PP 
JOIN HumanResources.Employee HRE
  ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group` and have both:

```
SELECT COUNT(MaritalStatus) as 'Status'
    FROM Person.Person PP INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee HRE
    ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
  group by MaritalStatus;
```

or you can use `decode`

Comment: Note #1: 'decode' operator is available in Oracle RDMS only.

Comment: Note #2: A note for anyone who stumble upon this answer in future. For OP's situation (getting sub-counts from the table) this answer will work great but it may cause issue when the intention is to get the total row count of the table also as an additional column and some of the 'MaritalStatus' columns are NULL. In that case the sum of all the sub-counts will not be equal to the total row count.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL this should work:

```
SELECT SUM(MaritalStatus = 'M') as 'Married',
       SUM(MaritalStatus = 'S') as 'Single'
FROM Person.Person PP INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee HRE
ON PP.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID
WHERE MaritalStatus IN ('M', 'S');
```

("MaritalStatus = 'X') is a boolean that evaluates to 0 (false) or 1 (true). On other servers than MySQL, a cast may be necessary.